# Qt does not show images

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt5.1

Problem show in the link below:
http://postimg.org/image/sp9mm85qb/

I try to add this image in code

```
    QIcon iconmain("qrc:/img/main.png");
    ui->tabWidget->tabBar()->setTabIcon(1,iconmain);
```

Tried to add image from resourse file from disk. But it still invisible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing msvs compil to mingv

Answer (score 1):

I assume the image is in the resource file with the prefix **img**, so you would access it without the qrc text prefix: -

```
QIcon iconmain(":/img/main.png");
```